# Inclusive function timings in windows performance analyzer or xperf

Tags: winapi, xperf

Is it possible to show inclusive function timings, i.e. the total time a function and all its children ran in the windows performance analyzer and/or xperf. I want to know the time independent of the caller.

I know I can get the inclusive timings dependent on the caller from the stack column, and the exclusive timings from the function column, but the first one summed up over all callers is really what I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

Right-click in the stack on a function you want to know the inclusive timing for and select `Butterfly->View Callers`

Comment: In WPA (the new trace viewer that ships with Windows Performance Toolkit) there is no butterfly menu so just right-click and select `View Callers` -> `By Function`